# Active_admin double render error message if i try return false or redirect to in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I got message **AbstractController::DoubleRenderError** in **Admin::AdminsController#update**

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return"

also `redirect_to(...)` and `return` not helped :(

How to fix that my problem? Help me, please? I want render error flash message and not update all stuff after if check_card_enabled? if in If return true. Thanks!

```
def update_resource(object, attributes)
  if check_card_enabled?
    redirect_to admin_admin_path(@admin)
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t('errors.messages.please_add_gateway_info')
    return false
  end
  update_method = if attributes.first[:password] == attributes.first[:password_confirmation] &&
      attributes.first[:password].present? || attributes.first[:password_confirmation].present?
                    :update_attributes
                  else
                    :update_without_password
                  end
  object.send(update_method, *attributes)
end

def check_card_enabled?
  @admin.card_disabled? && (params[:admin][:card_disabled] == '0') && @admin.gateway_info.nil?
end
```

## Anser:

```
before_filter :check_card_enabled, only: :update

def check_card_enabled
  admin = Admin.find_by(email: params[:admin][:email])
  if admin.card_disabled? && (params[:admin][:card_disabled] == '0') && admin.gateway_info.nil?
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t('errors.messages.please_add_gateway_info')
    redirect_to edit_admin_admin_url(admin)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to return from method when doing redirect. It actually only adds appropriate headers for the response object.

You can write more rubyish way:

```
if some_condition
    return redirect_to(path_one)
end
```

so according to your code try :-

```
def update_resource(object, attributes)
  if check_card_enabled?
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t('errors.messages.please_add_gateway_info')
    return redirect_to admin_admin_path(@admin), 
  end

 ....
 ....
```

Comment: not helped.        if check_card_enabled?
        flash[:alert] = I18n.t('errors.messages.please_add_gateway_info')
        return redirect_to admin_admin_path(@admin)
      end

Comment: Can you add the **debugger** or **binding.pry** after end to check that if condition is true then also below code executed or not ??

Comment: i use RubyMine. If condition true, code below not run

Comment: Ahhh! can you remove redirect_to means use only return then check what happend or where it redirects you ?